# Visual Studio Report Viewer Control 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reportviewer2008

I used the Report Viewer Control with SQL 2005 a few years ago. Back then I had to download and install the control manually, even for development, if I remember this correctly.
It appears that VS 2008 is supposed to come with this control, and it is supposed to be in the Data section in the Toolbox. I am using VS 2008 Database Edition and don't have a report viewer control in the data section. 
Is the documentation wrong or does the Database edition of Visual Studio not come with the Report Viewer control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are refering to the MicrosoftReportViewer, mine is under the Reporting Section.

OK, right click in the Database section, and select choose items, it should bring a box containing controls that can be added. Scroll down to ReportViewer. I have 2 available, one Winforms, one WebForms. Select the Winforms component.

Comment: No, I am referring to the ReportViewer control, as explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252104(VS.80).aspx
I don't know what the MicrosoftReportViewer control is or does.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. Would give you more than 1 point if I could.